# Pinching an edge in the middle of geometry without additional creasing

Tags: modeling, modifiers, geometry, subdivision-surface

So, I'm modeling a car and I've encountered a rather unexpected problem. When I add subdivision modifier to my low poly starting model to smooth things out, I still want to keep sharp edges on some places. And some of those places are in the middle of other geometry. I've dealt with this before, always with adding additional creasing, but in this case, this ruins the shape of my model.

I ask for a way to sharpen edges in middle of other geometry, without adding additional creasing.

Oh, just for information, extruding edges inwards and then adding creases to newly created edges works only on right (look picture 4.).

Here are some pictures:

[image]

1. Edges I want to make sharp are those that already have creases on them.

[image]

2. Picture #1 in wireframe.

[image]

3. Original geometry.

[image]

4. Extruding edges inwards and then adding creases to newly created edges (works only on right).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extrude the vertices in the corners, then add edge crease to the newly created edges:

[image]

These edges won't be rendered.

It seems that the direction has no/few influence on the result:

[image]

Comment: Oh thanks, haven't really occured to me to only add an edge. Additional geometry (like in my 4. picture) is only cousing wierd smoothing of subdivided mesh.

Comment: @martinsifrar, though, I need to add that this is very unconventional and not something I recommend... much more a trick. but easy and adds very few additional geometry.

Comment: I´m aware of that. Anyway I´m probably going to retopologize it afterwards. Do you think that it will cause some weird problems with edge of of the mesh?

Comment: @martinsifrar, I don't think so. For instance, if you apply the subdivision modifier (and remove these vertices), all seem to be ok about the resulting topo.